# The right way to create "image blocks" for a Drupal frontpage

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've created a layout with "Panels" to replace my frontpage and I have some doubts about how to populate the different panes. All my websites until now are "blog-like" websites with a typical "CMS-blog" look-like and I'm not sure what's the "Drupalish" way of solving some problems...

I'm trying to replicate the look and feel of websites like http://www.comicrelief.com, I mean, I've created a layout with Panels similar to that and I'm trying to populate the different panes with image content.

My doubt is about how to populate the layout with "image blocks" with an image "filling" the entire pane, and allow me to fade on mouseover to a different image with jquery.

My first (wrong, I imagine) approach is to upload the 2 images to the drupal site and create an Custom Full HTML block with CSS and using css background / img to display the image, and use jQuery to fade between the 2 images in case of hover. I mean, the entire block would be pure css/html/js doing this.

I don't think that's the right way to do it, because if an editor wants to change the "pane" contents, it has to upload images and edit HTML/JS manually.

I'm not sure how should I do it ... I was thinking in:

- Create a content-type called "home_block" with title + body + destination_url + image1 +  image2 (2 images for the fade effect on hover, and have both images of fixed NxM pixels so that they fit exactly in the pane).
- Create a layout with panels with different panes (future "image blocks") like featured-pane, lastnews-pane, static1-pane, ad-pane).
- Create a taxonomy to tag home_block content with "featured", "lastnews", "static1", "ad".
- Create views to query the DB and populate each pane with the newest item of each tag. Example: featured-pane = view that gets the last home_block tagged with "featured-pane" and displays only the thumbnailed/styled image.
- link each image to the content-type "destination_url".

That way, the editors would be able to add (and tag) new content that will appear in the front page automatically (the view always gets the newest content).

- Is that the right way to populate a front page created with "image blocks"?
- How do I "style" the view output so that I can link each "thumbnail" to the destination_url?
- Where or how do I add the jquery's hover effect between the 2 content-type images returned by the view?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found nodequeue very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your criteria I think the best option for you is to create a content type like you mentioned above with one image field as well as the other fields you mentioned.  Once you've done that create a block view that aggregates all of the latest pieces of content from that content type and displays it in the panel.

You can also use the [nodequeue module](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) to allow the admin to add/remove items from the queue and even rearrange what order they show.